# Почему при создании базы данных вылазит ошибка?

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных

Нажимаю на ConsoleApp3.csproj -> добавить -> создать элемент -> база данных. После этого VS зависает и вылазит эта ошибка. В проекте нету ни кода, ни каких-то еще строк. Просто в пустой проект я добавил базу данных.
[image: Скрин ошибки]

Comment: "Сервер не найден или не доступен" - возможно, не установлена сама СУБД. Смотрите в инсталляторе Студии наличие Sql Server Express LocalDB

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov СУБД установил сейчас, да. Ошибка пропала, но теперь вылазит ошибка 56.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Сейчас скину скрин

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov https://imgur.com/BbTp1QO